# C++, способен ли современный компилятор оптимизировать следующее?

Tags: c++, оптимизация, компилятор

Рассмотрим следующую ситуацию:

- Есть некая структура данных, пускай это будет `std::unordered_map`;
- Эта структура содержит определенные объекты;
- В какой-то момент мы обращаемся к объекту по ключу `key`;
- Затем делаем много всего, что гарантированно не изменяет состояние отображения и объектов в нем;
- Затем мы вновь обращаемся к объекту по ключу `key`;

Мой вопрос заключается в следующем: способен ли современный компилятор понять, что повторное обращение к объекту, который не менялся, как и структура данных, в которой он находится, является избыточным?

То есть, нужно ли оптимизировать такие вещи руками?

Comment: Можете поэкспериментировать тут https://godbolt.org/

Comment: короткий ответ: да, способен, но лучше  не оставлять всю работу компилятору.

Comment: я бы сказал, что поиск в `unordered_map` достаточно быстрый и врядли будет узким местом, если конечно нет коллизий. А если есть коллизии и их много, то надо что-то более эффективное думать

Comment: Я понимаю, что лучше все делать руками. Но ведь ситуации бывают разные. Например, возвращать из индексатора ссылку на элемент - идея так себе, потому что объект может подвергнуться переиндексации, и ссылки станут недействительными. Брать же копию нужного объекта заранее - еще хуже, потому что это хоть и безопасно в плане потенциальной переиндексации, но, все же, такой вариант усложняет логику и замусоривает код. То есть, бывают ситуации, в которых, действительно, сообразительность компилятора становится очень и очень важна.

Comment: Ну никто вам не говорил усложнить логику.

Comment: Как минимум - вы объявили используемую структуру константной?... А вообще - что значит "современный компилятор"? Один сможет, другой нет, третий при каких-то ключиках... Оптимизация **не является предметом стандарта**. И еще - не занимайтесь преждевременной оптимизацией. Сделали, проверили, профилировали, нашли, что узкое место именно здесь - вот тогда и не раньше можно начинать думать над этой конкретной оптимизацией...

Comment: @Harry, полностью с вами согласен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По крайней мере **g++ 7.4.0 -O3** такую оптимизацию **не смог** провести ни с `unorderd_map`, ни с `map`.

В простейшем тесте `std::map<int, int> x; x[2] = 1; std::cout << x[2] << '\n'; return x[2];` функция поиска в RB-tree вызывается дважды, хотя ее код генерится в том же ассемблерном файле.

Для `std::unordered_map` картина та же самая.

Возможно это происходит из-за приписанного ей атрибута `weak` (следовательно, реализация может быть заменена при линковке) и у компайлера нет гарантий, что ее вызов с одними и теми же аргументами возвращает одинаковое значение.